# How to start postgresql server in Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku but I keep getting the same error I get locally when trying to start the server before starting the database:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Normally, I would just type `sudo service postgresql start` and that would solve it but it doesn't seem to work on Heroku bash.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if PostgreSQL addon is added to your project if not then you will need to add that by running
`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

For more option follow this link: https://www.heroku.com/postgres

Comment: And then use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable to see what you should connect to. That variable will contain the host, port, user, password, and database you need to use.